# Regex to replace mustache with a variable from another file

Tags: python, regex

I have a file containing variable.

The content in informations.json

```
{
"robot_name" : "Mike",
"robot_age" : 1,
"human_name": "Sully",
"creation_duration":20}
```

And I have a string like this :

app.py

```
str = '{robot_name} must conqueer the world his creator is {human_age}, she spent {cration_duraiton}
years to create his prototype'
```

I want to change what is the `{}` with their variable in the other file so i can have

```
Mike must conqueer the world his creator is Sully, she spent  20 years to create his prototype
```

Is there way to do it with regex ?

Comment: FYI, those characters are called [curly brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) or braces, not "mustaches"?

Comment: Yes sorry, i couldn't find the name forget about it.

Comment: Just trying to help you improve your vocabulary since you're still learning.

Comment: Yes I know and thank you sir so much.